# A 2 dimensional Sharkovskii type Theorem

Tags: gn.general-topology

Does there exist a homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a periodic point of period three and no fixed points? Note that according to a theorem from Brouwer such homeomorphism must be orientation reversing.